# Unable to translate "more than a week ago" on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization, traducir

The sentence "more than a week ago" for the last seen section on the profile page is not available to translate.
I can't find it in [traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=more%20than%20a%20week%20ago).

Could this please be fixed?

> [image: More than a week ago]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term should now be there, ready for translation.

Comment: The term is now there / translation is possible / profile page changed.